# Cannot remove private certificat that is not in use

Tags: azure

I am not able to remove a private certificate in Azure portal although it is not in use anymore. 
This is what I get:
cannot remove certificate with thumbprint XXXXXX because it is used for hostname
Any help?

Comment: Where is your private certificate ? In Key vault or else?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT I imported it into the azure portal. Deleted all usage of the certificate and still received this error.

Comment: HI, @Basilf, I want to know where is your certificate in portal. Not just Azure portal.  Can you supply more details? Thanks!